# "Close" traduzido para Encerrar e Fechar

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

A opção para fechar/encerrar uma pergunta (em Inglês "*close*") têm traduções diferentes em sitios diferentes.

**# No menu de ferramentas de moderador** (2 sitios):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**# Na pergunta:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha perspectiva de Português, ambas as palavras funcionam para descrever/traduzir "*close*". Acho contudo que uma delas deve ser retirada.

Comment: Não vejo mais nenhuma ocorrência de "encerrar" (ou variações) aqui. Se vir mais alguma, só avisar

Answer (score 2):

De acordo.

Sou favorável ao uso de "encerrar", pois passa melhor a ideia de que a discussão ao entorno da pergunta chegou ao fim. Apesar de ser possível extrair ideia similar de "fechar", fazê-lo parece forçar uma catacrese.